# Bootstrap Navbar Right with mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How I can insert a default button on a right of a navbar that works with mobile and don't collapse with a 3 bars button.

I tried to use this

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default"`></div>
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear at all and what else have you tried other then the default behavior of the navbar?

Comment: I need the code I inserted this code to just can be able to add a question